# Trying to access saved data but getting error

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I’m trying to access a variable but im getting am error this is my code

It was working before I switched off my device but now its giving me error does anyone know what I’ve done wrong or have any suggestions?

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ItemDetail: View {
    let item: MenuItem
    @State var Amount: Int = 1
    @State var amountCoice: String = "Servings"
    @State var Calories: Int = 0
    @State var ItemsInMeal: [String] = []
    @State var Price: Int = 0
    
   
    var body: some View {
            VStack{
            
            HStack(){
                TextField("weigth", value: $Amount, formatter: NumberFormatter())
            }
            Menu {
                Button {
                    self.amountCoice = "kcal"
                    print(self.amountCoice)
                }label: {
                    Text("kcal")
                }
                
                Button {
                    self.amountCoice = "Grams"
                    print(self.amountCoice)
                } label: {
                    Text("grams")
                }
                Button {
                    self.amountCoice = "Servings"
                    print(self.amountCoice)
                } label: {
                    Text("servings")
                }}label: {
                    Text("Choice amount")
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.up")
                }
                Image("\(item.thumbnailImage)@2x").clipShape(Circle())
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text(item.name)
                    Text("$\(item.price)")
                }
                Button{
                    self.ItemsInMeal.append(item.name)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(ItemsInMeal, forKey: "ItemsInMeal")
                    Price += item.price 
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(Price, forKey: "Price")
                    print("\(self.ItemsInMeal), price: $\(self.Price)")
                } label: {
                    Text("add")
                }
             
            } 
            .onAppear(){
                self.ItemsInMeal = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "ItemsInMeal")! ///here’s where i get the error “An implicitly unwrapped optional was found here”///
                self.Price = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Price")
                
            }
        }    
    }
```

I’ve tried adding a ?? Self.ItemsInMeal = []
But that’s not what’s happening  and I’ve also tried using an ! But it still gives me an error
The error An implicitly unwrapped optional by the place where i set ItemsInMeal to The saved data
I am a new coder and have no clue what this means

Comment: What error? Compile time? Run time? Where?

Comment: You are not telling us what kind of error you are getting and what line in your code it is that generates the error.

Comment: Wild guess, if it's the first line of `.onAppear` then add `?? []` at the end.

Comment: Value of optional type [String]? Must be un wrapped to value type [String]

Comment: And the error is changes sometimes to  an explicitly unwrapped object was found in ItemDetail.swift on line 58. 58 is the line where i set itemsInMeal to the stored value. And i’m sorry for forgetting to write what error i got i was in a rush to post this question i had to get to my class

Comment: Well you have your answer then.

Comment: @Ethan2011 for readability, please [edit] your question and include all important info instead of adding it to the comments. See also [ask].

Comment: @koen thanks for the tip I’ve done that if you have any more tips id love to know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1):

UserDefaults will return nil if ItemsInMeal has not been saved yet. You need to provide a default value like this:

```
 self.ItemsInMeal = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "ItemsInMeal") ?? []
```

In general, it's best to avoid force unwrapping with !